# How can I test(or run) Intellij IDEA run configuration in CI?

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, configuration

I have some configurations in IDEA those saved in the project as XML files and I want them to be tested/verified in CI. I want to test them to make sure they could be running and will run successfully. 
How can I do that?

Addition 1: For example, let's see this XML:

```xml
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="CurrenciesApp" type="SpringBootApplicationConfigurationType" factoryName="Spring Boot" nameIsGenerated="true">
    <module name="sba-currencies-service" />
    <extension name="coverage">
      <pattern>
        <option name="PATTERN" value="aero.s7.*" />
        <option name="ENABLED" value="true" />
      </pattern>
    </extension>
    <option name="SPRING_BOOT_MAIN_CLASS" value="aero.s7.CurrenciesApp" />
    <option name="ALTERNATIVE_JRE_PATH" />
    <method v="2">
      <option name="Make" enabled="true" />
    </method>
  </configuration>
</component>
```

Addition 2: I'm stuck now in searching for some Maven plugin that can run those configurations.

Comment: Could you add some snippets of what is present in the XML file?  What have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck.

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary I've added configuration example.